# How are phosphoglycerides different from phospholipids?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organophosphorus-compounds, lipids

*(Currently studying high-school Biochemistry)*

I'm unable to distinguish between *phospholipids* and *phosphoglycerides* from their "definitions" (Courtesy: Wikipedia)

On *phospholipids*:

[image]

Which suggests that phospholipids **necessarily** contain a glycerol "bridge" that connects the fatty acid tail to the phosphate head. To me, this looks like,

[image]

On *phosphoglycerides*:

[image]

"Glycerol-based phospholipids"?! But aren't phospholipids *already* 'glycerol-based'?

If both phospholipids are glycerol-based, and if phosphoproteins are "glycerol-based phospholipids"...how are they any different?

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphingosine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phospholipids of a lipid bilayer can be divided in to two groups:

1. Those derived from glycerol -  phosphoglycerides.
2. Those derived from sphingosine -  sphingomyelin.

Phosphoglycerides are indeed a *type* of phospholipid.